# MicroSD card files recovery

Tags: memory, android-sdcard, sd-card, file-recovery

I have issue with microsd card. It worked fine on my android smartphone, but from one day phone didn't recognize it. When I plug in the card in my laptop(windows)(linux laptop don't see the card), laptop see it, but I can't get files through explorer and the card keep disconnecting-connecting every minute.
I can get file through Total Commander but it takes 2 minutes for one 3mb picture. How can I get photos from the card faster?

Answer (score 0):

The card may be worn/damaged.

I ran an room fan near some hard drives, and the transfer speeds improved.

Maybe use a bigger card as well?